# Zoom in Zoom Out TextView

Tags: android, android-listview

My listview contain textviews with text. I implemented a which on click. Increases all the textviews font of the listview. But when i ran the my sample, only one or two rows fonts changed and the other font remain to default. My question is how can i increase all fonts at once on button click.

my listadapter is as follows:

```
public class CommetaireAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private SampleListFragment activity;
    private ArrayList<Commentaire> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public static int selected_position_from_chapter=0;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    ViewHolder holder;
    static String src;

    public CommetaireAdapter(SampleListFragment context, ArrayList<Commentaire> d) {

        activity = context;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ((activity.getActivity()))
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getActivity());


    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.toArray().length;

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView txTime;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;

        //row
        if (convertView == null) {

            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_row, null);

            }else {

                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_row_odd, null);

            }

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txTime);

            vi.setTag(holder);

        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


        holder.txTime.setText(data.get(position).getDate());


        return vi;

    }
```

and in my listview class i pressed on zoomout button as follows:

```
btZoomOut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                CommetaireAdapter.ViewHolder.txTime.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,10);
                efficientadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also came on this type of requirement but the difference is it was Tab.
I solved it by using below code. Hope this will help you to get idea for your requirement.

```
for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++){
            TextView textTab=(TextView)tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            textTab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10f);
    }
```

This is not the exact solution i provided of your query but your problem is similar to what i faced.
So hope, this will help you to get this kind of idea for your query. :)

Best of Luck !!!!

*****SOLUTION (EDITED)* *******

```
 for(int i=0;i<yourListviewID.getChildCount();i++){
                    TextView textTab=(TextView)yourListviewID.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
// if your control is not textview, use your corretct one
                    textTab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10f);
        }
```

Let me know if still problem. :)

Comment: thanks i started a similar logic but can't i am still working on the issue.

Comment: to What control, you are binding this adapter??

Comment: i am using listview and arraylist

Comment: replace it with your ids. :)

Comment: yourListViewID means whatever the id you have given to your listview should go there. for example you have given id "listviewProduct" to your listview, then write listviewProduct.getChildCount(). Please replace the IDS with your IDS given by you to your control. Hope this clear your doubt. :)

Comment: Sorry for this i get confused for a second. Thanks you you're a genius dude. :). i learned how to count listview item and also how to modify its content. your solution is the best approach i found yet. Very grateful to you thanks again :)